# Find the generating function for the sequence and use it to find a closed formula for $c_n$

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4sdj = n$ where $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 n\geq0$ are all integers.  Suppose also that $x_2 \geq2$, $x_3$ is a multiple of 4, and $1 \leq{x_4}\geq3$.  Let $c_n$ be the number of solutions of the equation subject to these restrictions.  Find the generating function for the sequence ${c_n : n \geq0}$ and use it to find a closed formula for $c_2$.

I have been reading up on generating functions, but could use help better understanding it.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where do you find difficulty?  Also the question is unclear (what is sdj?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant $1 \leq x_4 \leq 3$. The generating function is $$G(t) = (1 + t + t^2 + t^3 + \ldots)(t^2 + t^3 + t^4  + \ldots)(1 + t^4 + t^8 + \ldots)(t + t^2 + t^3)$$ The four terms correspond to the four variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$. The idea is that every way to create a sum $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = n$ corresponds to a way to get a term $t^n$ in the $G(t)$. So $c_n$ is the coefficient of $t^n$ in $G(t)$. We see that the lowest term in $G(t)$ is $t^3$, so $c_2 = 0$. We could also have done this directly: we know that $x_1 \geq 0$, $x_2 \geq 2$, $x_3 \geq 0$ and $x_4 \geq 1$ and it follows that $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 \geq 0 + 2 + 0 + 1 = 3 > 2$